# HttpClient GetStringAsync() throwing an exception

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on MediaFire Api for i'm using rest api for authenthecation when i use this url for in Chrome poster and fifefox poster using 'GET' request Response is coming and i implemneted the same trough code to get response but throwing an exception like

> Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters.
>   Parameter name: name.

```
requestUrl = https://www.mediafire.com/api/1.1/user/get_session_token.php?  email=windowsphone654321@gmail.com&password=123456AaAa&application_id=42403&signature=506fbb1e62c51c20e50425022e3bca7dabfecca3&token_version=2
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var res = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUrl);
```

Comment: You will need to provide NETMON or Fiddler traces.

Comment: could please explain me briefly @Kiewic

Comment: I need to see the headers, to find out if something in the headers is wrong. But I don't have access to the API you are using.

Comment: There are no headers for this url please paste the Url in browser so that you can get the response.The reference Url is [link](http://www.mediafire.com/developers/core_api/1.1/getting_started/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async Task SendHttpClientRequest( Uri uri )
            {
            try
                {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync( uri );
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = string.Empty;
                responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            catch ( HttpRequestException e )
                {
                Debug.WriteLine( "\nException Message :{0} ", e.Message );
                }
            }
```